# How to click on span class using VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I need to click on button "exportar". How can I do this?

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" title="" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button-default" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Exportar</span></button><button type="button" title="" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button-cancel" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">CANCELAR</span></button></div>
```

Ive been trying with but got nothing up to now. like

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/following-sibling::button/span").Click
```

or

```
bot.find_element_by_xpath ("//span[text()='Exportar']")
```

Comment: try this bot.find_element_by_css_selector('span.ui-button-text')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Exportar** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("div.ui-dialog-buttonset > button.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-only.button-default > span.ui-button-text").click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button-default']/span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Exportar']").click
  ```